# How can I divide a drawing into a unequal size blocks using Paint.NET?

Tags: charts, disk-image, paint.net, bitmaps

I have a magnificent set of hand drawn rune cards that I wish to scan into a runic encyclopedia of some sort. Each card is 100mm x 80mm, so I could fit 6 per A4 page to scan them. After a little edit, I have four 240mm x 200mm images that each comprise 6 runes.

Is there a way I can get Paint.NET to divide these images, e.g. "here, divide this .jpg into 6 smaller, equal size ones?

Comment: It is hard to perfectly align multiple items on a scanner multiple times so that you could automate this and get perfect results.  Separating 24 images isn't a monumental task one at a time.  Almost any image editor will let you fine tune the selection area and crop out each image.  Or just scan the cards individually (easier to align).  Make the composite by combining the individual images into a grid (either by pasting onto a larger canvas or pasting into a grid or table in your document software).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paint.NET is hardly the right tool for this job. You may batch process image files with [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php). See example [here](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/tidbits/image.php#crop2)

In your case, the command will be something like

```
convert card_240x200.jpg -crop 80x100 +repage card_80x100_%d.jpg
```